# Tomcat not decoding post data

Tags: tomcat, wicket, tomcat7

Platform : Tomcat 7.0.21 on Ubutnu 11.10

We use apache wicket on tomcat which is fronted by apache2 using proxypass.

Facing an interesting problem where post data is not being decoded correctly. Example is

- Post "Hello World" (without quotes) to the server
- Observe in firebug/similar tools, that it got sent as expected ("Hello+World")
- Tomcat returns the value as "Hello+World" when I try to get url parameters

This happens only on one server, so it's obvious that I am missing something in the configuration, but could not figure out what. URIEncoding for the connector is set to "UTF-8". Code basing running at all location is same - coming from same war file.

Addtional observations:

- Problem occurs only one server
- Problem occurs whether I use apache2 front or not if I am posting data
- Problem **does not** happen when I use "get" with same parameters. Tried firebugs copy url with parameters and it works whether I have apache2 in front or not.
- Using debugger, verified that wicket actually returns encoded data. At lower level tomcat servlet request parameters show encoded values.

Comment: Are you running Tomcat with the same JVM ?

Comment: Yes, I am running same jvm.

Comment: Is there any firewall, deep packet inspector on your network ?

Comment: As far as I know nothing. Server is hosted at amazon if that matters. We have standard firewalls on, but it should apply to all the servers and not just one.

By the way, I upgraded the tomcat to latest and greatest - 7.0.39 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the problem is. As a desperate major I decided to upgrade the tomcat. Now with latest version available as of this writing - 7.0.39, I am not facing this problem any more.